# How would I return a document and subarray using aggregate and unwind?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the following mongoose query to return the most popular snack items from a document. Below is the document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("58d7d2d760b78902f1df3fa2"),
  "user_id": ObjectId("58d2dd4c8207c28149dbc748"),
  "calories": 2000,
  "date": 20170226,
  "snacks": [
{
  "nutrients": {
    "protein": 7.5,
    "carbs": 56.5,
    "fat": 10.5
  },
  "servings": 23.8,
  "calories": 526,
  "name": "Dairy milk"
},
"dinner": [ ],
"lunch": [ ],
"breakfast": [ ]
}
```

I then use the following query:

```
user_food.aggregate({$unwind: $snacks},{$sortByCount: $snacks.name},function(err, results){
        if(err){
            console.log("something went wrong: " + err);
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else{
            return res.status(200).send(results);
        }
    });
```

This returns:

```
_id:"Dairy milk"
count:3
```

What I need to be returned is the whole object:

```
"nutrients": {
"protein": 7.5,
"carbs": 56.5,
"fat": 10.5
},
"servings": 23.8,
"calories": 526,
"name": "Dairy milk",
count:3
```

Comment: Your document example is not a valid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$sortByCount`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortByCount/) is equivalent to `$group` by `_id` + `$sort`. To add more fields in the `$group` stage, you will need to to use [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) to take the first value of the specified field :

```
user_food.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$snacks"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$snacks.name",
        snacks: { $first: "$snacks" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        count: -1
    }
}], function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("something went wrong: " + err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        return res.status(200).send(results);
    }
});
```

You will get something like the following :

```
{
    "snacks": {
        "nutrients": {
            "protein": 7.5,
            "carbs": 56.5,
            "fat": 10.5
        },
        "servings": 23.8,
        "calories": 526,
        "name": "Dairy milk",
    },
    count: 3
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Ive edited it slightly to allow the user to decide which meal to choose the popularity but apart from that it has worked exactly how I needed. thank you so much.